# "Hello, World", Even before it runs

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, compile-time

> ***Warning: This challenge is only valid for languages with a compiler.***

Make a program (which is perfectly valid code) that outputs `Hello, World`, even before runtime.

How? Let me explain.

Many languages have a compiler. Some operations are made in the compile-time, and others, in runtime. You trick the compiler to output the text `Hello, World` in compile-time. The text can be anywhere, like the build log.(Not errors. sorry for invalidating all those answers. at least theres pragma tho)

> You can use C, C++ or C#, but I wouldn't encourage you to. It's simply a game breaker.

p.s. I wrote this challenge because the tag [compile-time](/questions/tagged/compile-time) is both unused, and used wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't the simple source code `Hello, World!` be optimal in almost any compiled language where that line is not valid code and the offending line gets printed in an error message?

Comment: "which is perfectly valid code" ... "The text can be anywhere, like the build log, **an error**, anywhere" ... what's "perfectly valid code" then?

Comment: I would say, better ask the “Hello, World!” to appear both when compiling and when running. That would make clear what is valid code.

Comment: @manatwork Or use two different strings so that you can't just get the line output during compiling that has the string for the actual running.

Comment: I have to agree with @MartinEnder. Almost all programming languages with a compiler will output the incorrect source code with an error class/function/something is missing. Just take my posted Java answer for example. This would be a valid answer in almost all programming languages with a compiler.. So although I barely do this, I give this a -1 vote for being boring, straight-to-the-point in more than 90% of the the compiler languages, and kinda pointless challenge. Sorry..

Comment: Are custom file names allowed?

Comment: Does the code have to compile to an executable or is an object file enough?

Comment: This would've been cool, but you didn't spend much time on the question :(.

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 51 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Sy7Wzc3Py///X7k8sSgvMy9dwSM1JydfRyE8vygnhSs5J7G4WCGkurgksSQzWaEsPzNFwTcxM09Ds7q29v9/AA)

```
#warning Hello, World
class P{static void Main(){}}
```

Prints the following to the Error List (but still compiles):

```
warning CS1030: #warning: `Hello, World'
```

Comment: OP has updated that errors are not allowed. Just use `#warning` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## FreePascal, 29 characters

```pascal
begin{$INFO Hello, World}end.
```

Maybe other Pascal variants too, not sure whether the [`$INFO`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu35.html) directive is FreePascal only or not.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ fpc compile-time-message.pas 
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.2+dfsg-2 [2017/04/09] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2017 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling compile-time-message.pas
User defined: Hello, World
Linking compile-time-message
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?
0 lines compiled, 0.0 sec
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

```c
Hello, World;main;
```

This compiles just fine with gcc (and clang), although the program it produces crashes immediately.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/98jNScnX0chPL8oJ8U6NzEzz/r/fwA)

#### Compiler output

gcc 6.3.1 produces the following debugging information.

```
.code.tio.c:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 Hello, World;main;
 ^~~~~
.code.tio.c:1:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘Hello’ [-Wimplicit-int]
.code.tio.c:1:8: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘World’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 Hello, World;main;
        ^~~~~
.code.tio.c:1:14: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 Hello, World;main;
              ^~~~
.code.tio.c:1:14: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘main’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 15 bytes

```bash
Hello, World;
```

If compiling to an object file is allowed, this works just as well. The resulting file simply declares two global variables.

The byte count includes **+3 bytes** for the compiler flag `-c`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQUa6XrGBjo6D33yM1JydfRyE8vygnxfq/HhdXenKygm4yRIWRnZohV0FRZl5JmoJ6bmJmnoZmda06UH9efoFeMlgpUF0@lKunn6iXX1ryHwA)

#### Compiler output

```bash
hw.c:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 Hello, World;
 ^~~~~
hw.c:1:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘Hello’ [-Wimplicit-int]
hw.c:1:8: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘World’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 Hello, World;
        ^~~~~
```

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 20 bytes

```c
main(Hello, World){}
```

This compiles to a program that exits cleanly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPwyM1JydfRyE8vygnRbO69v9/AA)

#### Compiler output

```c
.code.tio.c:1:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main(Hello, World){}
 ^~~~
.code.tio.c: In function ‘main’:
.code.tio.c:1:1: warning: type of ‘Hello’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
.code.tio.c:1:1: warning: type of ‘World’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

Comment: Weird, I swear I tried this and it didn't work for me. Have an upvote

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
m@main=m
```

8 bytes from the code plus 16 bytes for the compiler flag `-W'Hello, World'`.

Gives the warning `unrecognised warning flag: -WHello, World` and compiles the program.

Depending on the shell (or the absence of a shell) you can omit the single quotes in the flag for two bytes less. TIO works this way.

#### Haskell, TIO environment, 22 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P9chNzEzzzb3//9/yWk5ienF/3XDPYAy@ToK4flFOSkA)

Edit: @Dennis saved a byte. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 15 bytes

14 bytes of code + `-w` flag.

```
"Hello, World"
```

When ran with `-w` flag, it produces the compile-time warnings:

```
$ perl -we '"Hello, World"'
Useless use of a constant ("Hello, World") in void context at -e line 1.
```

And if you wonder if it really happens at compile time, you can add `-c` flag, which causes the program to be compiled but not ran, and the warning is still here.

Answer (score 0):

### GNU C, 31 bytes

Nothing clever here. I'm mostly posting it for reference.

```c
main(){printf("Hello, World");}
```

GCC will throw the following warning at compilation time:

```
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:1:8: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
 main(){printf("Hello, World");}
        ^
```

Comment: Can't you use `puts` for -2?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer With my version of GCC at least, `puts()` would compile  without a warning.

Comment: Can you use `f` instead of `main`?

Comment: @musicman523 Would a C program without a main() compile at all?

Comment: @Arnauld You could use the `-c` flag to compile without linking, it would just be unexecutable.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 23 bytes

```c
main(){"Hello, World";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7NaySM1JydfRyE8vygnRcm69v9/AA)

Gives the warning:

```c
warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
main(){"Hello, World";}
^~~~
```

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 38 bytes

```cpp
#pragma message"Hello, World"
main(){}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/X7mgKDE9N1EhN7W4ODE9VckjNScnX0chPL8oJ0WJKzcxM09Ds7r2/38A)

Rather than using compiler warnings, this answer uses a built-in `pragma` directive that allows printing notes to stdout. Works in C and C++ (as I *think* all the rest of these do).

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 23 + 1 = 24 bytes

```c
#define f"Hello, World"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU3JIzUnJ19HITy/KCdF6f//f8lpOYnpxf91kwE)

Prints "Hello, World!" as part of an error message, which says:

```c
warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name
 #define f"Hello, World!"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is a default warning in GCC; no flags need to be added to achieve this.

The extra byte comes from the `-c` flag, which successfully compiles the program without linking, which means it accepts not having a `main` function. However, the resulting output file cannot be executed. If this is unacceptable, then:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 31 bytes

```c
#define f"Hello, World"
main=0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU3JIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFiSs3MTPP1sD6/38A)

This will run, but will segfault every time. If *that*'s not acceptable, then:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 32 bytes

```c
#define f"Hello, World"
main(){}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU3JIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFiSs3MTNPQ7O69v9/AA)

Comment: `-c` counts as three bytes (one for the space). `main=0;` is the same as `main;`. `#define Hello, World` is shorter than `#define f"Hello, World"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```scala
object F extends App{"Hello, World"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/z8/KSs1uUTBTSG1oiQ1L6VYwbGgoFrJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFqfb/fwA)

Gives the warning:

```scala
warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
object F{"Hello, World"}
```